# Hierarchical clustering using absolute values of correlation values

Tags: matlab, cluster-analysis, correlation, hierarchical-clustering

I'm trying to do hierarchical clustering in MATLAB using linkage and pdist funcitons. I'm familiar with the functions, but I'm attempting to cluster by the absolute value of the correlation values. The default for the pdist function, 'correlation', would include both the positive and negatives, but I'm interested in grouping inverse relationships as well. Does any know how I can change this? I've looked into editing the original pdist function but can't seem to find the right line.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried applying the `abs` function into your matrix?

And then clustering the matrix of absolute values.